# Performance issue when removing numbers from large string

Tags: c#, string

I have a function containing the following code:

```
Text = Text.Where(c => !Char.IsDigit(c)).Aggregate<char, string>(null, (current, c) => current + c);
```

but it is rather slow.  Is there anyway I can speed it up?

Comment: Here you go friend: `Text = "";`

Comment: Are you using `Char.IsDigit` because you need to handle international digits or because you don't know better?

Comment: The string contains just integers or also decimals?

Comment: Just curious, where are you taking that text from? Is it a user input?

Comment: To answer you questions, I want to remove individual characters that are numbers from user input.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
Text = Regex.Replace(Text, @"\d+", "");
```

`\d+` is more efficient than just `\d` because it removes multiple consecutive digits at once.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use `Regex.Replace`:

```
Text = Regex.Replace(Text, "\\d", "");
```

The regular expression matches a single digit. `Regex.Replace` replaces each occurrence of it in the `Text` string with an empty string `""`.

Comment: @TimPietzcker I am not sure about the relative efficiency of the two, because it depends a lot on the implementation of the `Replace` function.

Comment: If he doesn't need to handle international digits, `[0-9]` (10 characters) should be faster as it covers a much smaller range of characters than `\\d` (460 characters)

Comment: @Esailija That will make (almost) no difference. Character class lookup inside the regular expresson engine is highly optimised and takes roughly O(1), i.e. it’s independent of the number of characters in a character class. Everything else would make regular expressions a priori unusable.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's independent; what you suggest sounds like a hash table, not magic. But you have a point that it makes almost no difference, much like adding a `+`.

Answer (score 2):

All those concatenations are probably killing you. The easiest/best is probably a regex:

```
Text = Regex.Replace(Text, "\\d", "");
```

---

Or you can try making only one new string instance:

```
Text = new string(Text.Where(c => !Char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray())
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with [`Regex.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace.aspx);

> In a specified input string, replaces strings that match a regular
>   expression pattern with a specified replacement string.

```
Regex.Replace(Text, "\\d+", "");
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/6XCaJU).